# Debug Code: Sorting Royal names

Tags: python, string, algorithm, sorting

I got the following question in an exam and it failed some test cases which I don't have access to. The question is about sorting royal names with roman numerals. Given was a list of strings that we had to sort. The input obeyed the following constraints:

1) length of the list `1 <=n<= 50`

2)Each name started with a capital letter followed by a space followed by a roman numeral between 1 and 50 inclusive.

3) Each number is a Roman numeral with capital letters `I`, `V`, `X`, `L`.

The code is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
def decode(s):
    if s == "I":
        return 1
    elif s == "V":
        return 5
    elif s == "X":
        return 10
    elif s == "L":
        return 50

def romanToInt(num):
    res = 0

    for i in range(0, len(num)-1):
        if decode(num[i]) < decode(num[i+1]):
            res -= decode(num[i])
        else:
            res + decode(num[i])

    res = res + decode(num[len(num) - 1])
    return res


def getSortedList(names):

    if len(names) == 0:
        return []

    copy_names = [[a,a] for a in names]
    copy_names = sorted(copy_names, key=lambda x:x[0])
    for i in range(0, len(copy_names)):
        n2 = copy_names[i][0].split(" ")
        num = str(romanToInt(n2[1]))
        copy_names[i][0] = n2[0]+ " " + num


    copy_names = sorted(copy_names, key=lambda x:x[0])
    res = [a[1] for a in copy_names]

    return res


arr = ["Richard V","Henry VI","Edward II","Richard XXV","Henry IX","Edward L"]
print getSortedList(arr)
```

I have debugged this code with multiple inputs and can't figure out what the problem is. Can anyone please point out any mistake that I am overlooking?

Comment: `res + decode(num[i])` is definitely a problem. It should be `res += decode(num[i])`.

Comment: Is your program expected to reject invalid input? That is, what happens if somebody gives you a name, `"Richard IIV"` or `"Edward IL"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What output do you expect for:

```
["Edward IX","Edward L"]
```

The current program gives:

```
['Edward L', 'Edward IX']
```

i.e. 50 comes before 9.

I suspect you are meant to sort these in numerical order.

If so, the problem is that you are converting to a string before sorting.  In Python string comparison is lexicographic (i.e. normal alphabetic order) which means "9" > "50", while as integers, 9<50.

To fix, you could use a two stage comparison that first compares the name of the king as a string, then the number as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled list name in final res assignment. Change the following line

```
res = [a[1] for a in copy_name]
```

to

```
res = [a[1] for a in copy_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1 I used a custom class holding name, roman suffix and the integer value of roman suffix.
2 Used a comparator which sorts on the basis of integer value if names match.
3 romanToInt is implemented below.

  class Name{
        String first;
        String roman;
        int num;
        Name(String f, String r, int n){
            this.first = f;
            this.roman = r;
            this.num = n;
        }
    }
    List<String> sortRoyal(List<String> names){
        PriorityQueue<Name> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((x,y)->{
            if((x.first).compareTo(y.first)==0) return x.num - y.num;
            return (x.first).compareTo(y.first); 
        });

        for(String str : names){
            int index = str.indexOf(" ");
            String first = str.substring(0, index);
            String second = str.substring(index+1);
            int num = romanToInt(second);

            pq.add(new Name(first, second, num));
        }

        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        while(pq.size()!=0){
            Name curr = pq.remove(); 
            res.add(curr.first+" "+curr.roman);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public int romanToInt(String s) {
        int num = 0;
        for(int i =0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'I') num+=1;
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'V') {
                if(i>=1 && s.charAt(i-1) == 'I') num+=3;
                else num+=5;
            }
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'X') {
                if(i>=1 && s.charAt(i-1) == 'I') num+=8;
                else num+=10;
            }
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'L') {
                if(i>=1 && s.charAt(i-1) == 'X') num+=30;
                else num+=50;
            }
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'C') {
                if(i>=1 && s.charAt(i-1) == 'X') num+=80;
                else num+=100;
            }
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'D') {
                if(i>=1 && s.charAt(i-1) == 'C') num+=300;
                else num+=500;
            }
            if(s.charAt(i) == 'M') {
                if(i>=1 && s.charAt(i-1) == 'C') num+=800;
                else num+=1000;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

def decode(s):
if s == "I":
return 1
elif s == "V":
return 5
elif s == "X":
return 10
elif s == "L":
return 50

def romanToInt(num):
res = 0

```
for i in range(0, len(num)-1):

    if decode(num[i]) < decode(num[i+1]):
        res -= decode(num[i])
       
    else:
        res += decode(num[i])
    

res = res + decode(num[len(num) - 1])
return res
```

def getSortedList(names):

```
if len(names) == 0:
    return []

copy_names = [[a,a,a] for a in names]
copy_names = sorted(copy_names, key=lambda x:x[0])

for i in range(0, len(copy_names)):
    n2 = copy_names[i][0].split(" ")
    # print (n2)
    num = (romanToInt(n2[1]))
    # print(num)
    copy_names[i][2] = num
    copy_names[i][0] = n2[0]

# print(copy_names)
copy_names = sorted(copy_names, key=lambda x:x[2])
# print(copy_names)
copy_names = sorted(copy_names, key=lambda x:x[0])
# print(copy_names)
res = [a[1] for a in copy_names]

return res
```

arr = ["Richard LXV","Henry VI","Edward IX","Richard XXV","Henry IX","Edward L"]
print (getSortedList(arr))